# Partial Unique Index in Nested Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, unique-index, partial-index

My documents are like this:

```
{ a: [ { u: 1 }, {} ] },
{ a: [ { u: 2 }, {}, {} ] },
{ a: [ { u: 3 } ] }
```

And I want to create unique index on `a.u` if it exists:

```
{
    key: { 'a.u': 1 } },
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: { 'a.u': { $exists: true } }
}
```

The documents will be indexed like this:

```
u: 1    -> { a: [ { u: 1 }, {} ] }
u: 2    -> { a: [ { u: 2 }, {}, {} ] }
u: 3    -> { a: [ { u: 3 } ] }
u: null -> { a: [ { u: 1 }, {} ] }
u: null -> { a: [ { u: 2 }, {}, {} ] }  <-- duplicated key
```

Here comes the problem, there is a `a.u` in both records, so the partial filter expression matches both records. But both also have an empty element in the array with `a.u` of `null`, and I get the error of duplicated key because of this `null`.

Is there any way that I can solve this problem? Or I have to change the schema?

Comment: Do want `a.u` to be unique across all the documents or within a document?

Comment: @RaR I want `a.u` to be unique across all documents in the collection.